# Bash Parsing Large Log Files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am new to bash, awk, scripting; so do please help me improve.

I have huge number of text files, each several hundred MB in size. Unfortunately, they are not all fully standardized in any one format. Plus there is a lot of legacy in here, and a lot of junk and garbled text. I wish to check all of these files to find rows with a valid email ID, and if it exists then print it to a file named the first-char of the email ID. Hence, multiple text files get parsed and organized into files named a-z and 0-9. In case the email address starts with a special character, then it will get written into a file called "_" underscore. The script also trims the rows to remove whitespaces; and replaces single and double quotes (this is an application requirement)

My script works fine. There is no error/bug in here. But it is incredibly slow. My question: **is there a more efficient way to achieve this?** Parsing 30 GB logs takes me about 12 hrs - way too much! Will grep/cut/sed/another be any faster?

**Sample txt File**

```
!bar@foo.com,address
#john@foo.com;address
john@foo.com;address µÖ
email1@foo.com;username;address
email2@foo.com;username
  email3@foo.com,username;address   [spaces at the start of the row]
 email4@foo.com|username|address   [tabs at the start of the row]
```

**My Code:**

```
awk -F'[,|;: \t]+' '{
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "")
    if (NF>1 && $1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$/)
    {
        gsub(/"/, "DQUOTES")
        gsub("\047", "SQUOTES")
        r=gensub("[,|;: \t]+",":",1,$0)
        a=tolower(substr(r,1,1))
        if (a ~ /^[[:alnum:]]/)
            print r > a
        else
            print r > "_"
    }
    else
        print $0 > "ErrorFile"
}' *.txt
```

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to extract emails from files on this site and unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @l0b0 the question is not about how to extract email, there is custom conversion between input and output and OP already has a working example.. not sure why you marked it as duplicate.. the question may fit better on code review sites, but this is no way a duplicate

Comment: l0b0. this is incorrect. that was not my question. my awk code works - beautifully. but its slow. this is not about extracting emails, but about parsing data efficiently. Pls re-open my post

Comment: If you really want to make this fast, rewrite it in C (or C++ or Java or ...)

Comment: And also consider converting the files (once!) into a standard form that gets rid of all of the legacy crap, and is easier (faster) to read.  (Or if this is a once-off task, just let it run for 12 hours.)

Comment: Stephen, can you help code it for me in C?

Comment: @rogerwhite regex is costly and your file has non-ASCII characters, otherwise `LC_ALL=C` will provide a huge benefit.. if you have multiple cores on your machine, look into `GNU parallel` (I don't know how to use it)... it will allow you to break down your input file into smaller chunks, allow multiple process and then combine the output together

Comment: @rogerwhite re: `Will grep/cut/sed/another be any faster?` => consider @l0b0's comment about `lots of examples`, ie, have you looked at any of the other Q&A's to see if they're faster?